# MS Access converting people's names into numbers

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I am using a Make Table and/or Append query to get user names from a linked SharePoint list. In SharePoint, the names are selected from some list of employees. So it seems SharePoint is storing a number instead of the text of the name. However, when I create the query and then look at it in Datasheet View, it shows the names. But when I execute the query (Make Table or Append) it puts the number in the table instead of the name. I don't have any kind of list that shows which names go with which numbers. Is there a way to get Access to get the text instead of the number? I mean, Access HAS the name, because it shows it to me in the Datasheet View.

EDIT: (SOLVED) I discovered that when linking (via ODBC) to the SharePoint list, a table called 'UserInfo' tagged along. And that table has the IDs and Names that Access is using and that I am able to use to link the numbers to the name.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that when linking (via ODBC) to the SharePoint list, a table called 'UserInfo' tagged along. And that table has the IDs and Names that Access is using and that I am able to use to link the numbers to the name.